# getting the full filenames from all top directory files in a specific directory and suppressing the occuring error

Tags: c#, file, directory, filenames, directory-listing

I met a not expected problem with getting just the top directory full filenames from a specific directory. C# throws an error and doesn't list anything in the specific directory. 
But MS DOS has not a problem with my command: *"dir C:\windows\prefetch\*.pf"

**Visual Basics 6** old "*Dir Function*" also does it without complaining.
The "**Windows Explorer**" opens it up and doesn't ask anything from me. Also **"Nirsofts Tool Suit"** lists it instantly without any problem. No one of this tools needs to run with special permissions, just a double click on the application icon and ready is the task.

I looked around and found nothing here, what would answer this weird problem. My user can access the directory, if I go with any other application into it, now there is the question why C# throws
an "Unauthorized Access Exception" which is totally weird, since I have access in this folder.

I don't want to elevate my application with admin permissions for it nor create extra a xml for it to run it with highest privileges. The not trustful yellow elevation box must be avoided.

Now my question: How it comes that I can not list the filenames in this folder when all other
applications can do that.
What code do I need if "*Directory.GetFiles()"* fails?
Is there any flag or property in the framework directory class which allows my application access to the files, whatever.

Here my code which fails (using System.IO):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 0); //clear the textBox1

        //Unauthorized access exception and yellow bar in this line
        foreach(string FileX in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "prefetch"), "*.pf"))
        {
            textBox1.Text += FileX;
        }
    }
```

Comment: sharing your code will allow us find the cause

Comment: is this error comes at debugging time or after setup

Comment: Instead of searching for `*.pf` files, can you try to list all - `*`, what is the result you get ?

Comment: Do not use goto. Do not use Application.DoEvents. Do not clear a textbox, by sending keys to it. Do not use Sleeps in the UI thread. This is a big blob of "DO NOT DO THIS" code. Do yourself a favor, get rid of your VB mindset and learn programming. It will be a lot easier to help you with your problems, if your current problem is isolated and not burried in a pile of other problems.

Comment: Harsh but effective @nvoigt... feedwall, does it work if you get to the directory via a FolderBrowserDialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did I understand correctly that you only need the File-names with directory-names. 
This code works for me, no elevations needed.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string folder = @"C:\windows\prefetch";
        string filemask = @"*.pf";
        string[] filelist = Directory.GetFiles(folder, (filemask));

        //now use filelist[i] for any operations. 
    }
```

Comment: ok, did you try just the plain code? mine works in debug and as published exe. However I have win8 Pro x64. Good luck.